# CMD "Rename" command

Tags: cmd

I want to remove first 21 characters from every ".pdf" file in folder.

My command:

```
rename "*.pdf" "/////////////////////*.pdf"
```

The problem remains only the following: The first file is renamed twice. Deletes the first 42 characters. Other files are renamen correctly (21).

Comment: How many characters do your filenames have? Could you please provide some reproducible examples? (It may make more sense to keep the last _n_ characters).

Comment: What is to be done if the new filename is the same as another filename?

Answer (score 0):

This command would do it, but there are many undetected pitfalls. What if the filename does not have more than 21 characters? What if the NewName duplicates an existing filename?

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-ChildItem .\*.pdf |" ^
        "ForEach-Object { Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $($_.Name[21..($_.Name.Length)] -join '') -WhatIf }"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the file mask `*.pdf` may be "updated" with newly created files during the process.
The same goes for a simple `for %%a in (*.pdf)` loop.
To work around this, make sure, the list of files gets generated before `rename` does it's thing:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.pdf') do rename "%%a" "/////////////////////*.pdf"
```

The `do` part is only executed, after the (`...`) part is done, so newly created/changed files won't be processed a second time.

Same pitfalls as in lit's answer apply:
What if the filename does not have more than 21 characters?
What if the NewName duplicates an existing filename?